# Вывести элементы массива, 2ая буква которых "Е"

Tags: php

есть массив, допустим "вася", "дима", "леша", "наташа"

нужно вывести только те элементы, 2 буква которых "Е".

не могу найти как выбрать букву из элемента((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = array("вася", "дима", "леша", "наташа");

foreach($a as $tmp) {
    if ($tmp{1} == 'е') echo $tmp;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Если UTF-8:

```
if (mb_substr($tmp, 1, 1) == 'е') {}
```

Comment: я делал также но на выхде получаю "�" вместо букв. элементы массива берутcя из файла. везде кодиродка utf-8 with bom

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = array("вася", "дима", "леша", "наташа", "лева");

print_r(array_filter($a, function($d) {
    return mb_substr($d, 1, 1, 'utf8') == 'е';
}));
```

Comment: Кстати, один из "уникальных" способов) Мне почему-то в голову при попытке решить задачу "уникально", пришел только говнокод =) Ну, что ж, хоть улыбнемся :)

Comment: @Francesco нет, я бы не стал считать ваш код говнокодом со стороны самой реализации. Но, всё равно, вы добавили достаточно лишних операций :)

Comment: Да, правильно!

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array("вася", "дима", "леша", "наташа");

foreach($a as $tmp) {
    if (mb_substr($tmp, 1, 1, 'utf8') == 'е')
        echo $tmp;
}
```